# Trying to set Variable in the Place of URL

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to set a variable in the place of a URL. When I test my code in w3schools HTML tester it works, however when I put it into my Ionic project, it doesn't work in the slightest. Here is my code:

```
<script>
      let urls = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com", "https://patorjk.com"]
      let url = Math.floor((Math.random() * accounts1.length))
</script>
<script>
  document.write('<a href="' + (urls[url]) + '">Link</a>');
</script>>
```

This code works and sends me to one of the links above. However when I put it into my Ionic project it doesn't work and just displays a `>`. I'm sorry If my question is vague, this is one of my first posts. So thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working with what you've currently provided, could it be that accounts1 is undefined? Should that not be `urls.length`? You also have a phantom `>` at the end of the second `<script>` tag. By making the changes proposed, I can get it to work:

```html
<script>
  let urls = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com", "https://patorjk.com"];
  let url = Math.floor((Math.random() * urls.length));
</script>
<script>
  document.write('<a href="' + (urls[url]) + '">Link</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Its really weird, its not working at all for me. I import a screenshot if you would like. The href just isn't showing up for me. Its completely blank.

Comment: I've detected an issue. document.write isn't working at all, is there something that could be causing this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, but have you tried separating the document.write line:

`let linkElement = '<a href="' + (urls[url]) + '">Link</a>';`
`document.write(linkElement);`

Then you can identify if it's the building of the string, or the actual document.write function causing the issue.